# What is url for npm packages repository?

Tags: npm-install

I have installed node js and npm on my windows But when I try to install npm modules(packages) using

```
command>>npm install -g xxxx(package name)
```

It doesn't get installed, and it asked me to check proxy setting. As I am working on private network, so may be it doesn't allow me to access the url from which npm packages get downloaded.

Please tell me what is url for such npm packages from where it gets downloaded so that I can ask my network provider to give access for that site.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

All npm packages are in fact downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com). However, npm resolves those GitHub dependencies via https://www.npmjs.com.

For example, express https://github.com/expressjs/express is the download link.

```
npm install -g express (or without -g).
```

The system does not know the GitHub location of the express package. So it must first lookup https://www.npmjs.com to get GitHub url. Then it will  clone the package.

Comment: That's just wrong. 
npmjs has it's own hosting for packages and they're downloaded as tar archives.
You can also have npm clone a git repository as a package but it's not the default behavior.

Answer (score 12):

NPM packages are downloaded from https://registry.npmjs.org unless otherwise configured.

You can get the download URL for a package with `npm view`, for example JQuery:

```
npm view jquery dist.tarball
```

returns: https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-3.5.1.tgz

You can change the default registry with `npm set registry <new url>`; this is typically used in large institutions or corporations with an internal registry mirror.